# FireandForget delegate - c#

Tags: c#

I came across this link, [link text](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20060727.asp)

In the article, where the author has definition of this method

```
static void WriteIt(string first, string second, int num)
```

I changed that in my test app to this

```
static void WriteIt(CustomerObject Customer)
{
  fileIO.CreateFile(XMLUtil.Serialize(Customer));
}
```

Where

```
 public static string Serialize(object o)
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");

        return Serialize(o, ns);

    }

    public static string Serialize(object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces ns)
    {
        try
        {
            using (System.IO.MemoryStream m = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {

                //serialize messagelist to xml
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(o.GetType(), "");

                if (ns != null)
                    serializer.Serialize(m, o, ns);
                else
                    serializer.Serialize(m, o);

                m.Position = 0;
                byte[] b = new byte[m.Length];
                m.Read(b, 0, b.Length);

                return System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "Ex = " + ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

This method always gives an exception

```
static void EndWrapperInvoke (IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        wrapperInstance.EndInvoke(ar); 
        ar.AsyncWaitHandle.Close();
    }
```

Stacktrace:

Server stack trace:

```
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
   at SRC.FileMover.ThreadUtil.InvokeWrappedDelegate(Delegate d, Object[] args)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.PrivateProcessMessage(RuntimeMethodHandle md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.EndInvokeHelper(Message reqMsg, Boolean bProxyCase)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(Object NotUsed, MessageData& msgData)
   at SRC.FileMover.ThreadUtil.DelegateWrapper.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result)
   at SRC.FileMover.ThreadUtil.EndWrapperInvoke(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.AsyncResult.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.AgileAsyncWorkerItem.DoAsyncCall()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.AgileAsyncWorkerItem.ThreadPoolCallBack(Object o)
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallbackInternal(_ThreadPoolWaitCallback tpWaitCallBack)
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback(Object state)
```

UPDATE 1:
Trying to run my app and get the full exception. It seems like its happening at different locations. I will repost my ? again shortly.  I think it may be wise if I can post my application. Can i upload a .zip file or is it better to just post the .cs code that I am using?

Comment: You need to ask a question...

Comment: The top of the exception is missing too

Answer (score 3):

If you want to fire and forget a method, you should use the ThreadPool:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => SomeMethod(someParameter), null);
```

Comment: The one caveat to this is that the thread pool is not recommended for long-running methods - there are only a limited number of threads available for background tasks, and the MSDN documentation recommends using them only for relatively short-lived operations. Long running methods should be started on their own dedicated thread. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to fire and forget a method, why not just declare an anonymous method with an Action?

```
Action<CustomerObject> fireAndForget = delegate(CustomerObject obj) 
{
     fileIO.CreateFile(XMLUtil.Serialize(obj));
};

fireAndForget.BeginInvoke(new CustomerObject()); // Don't need to End Invoke
```

Comment: **You are wrong**.  You _always_ do need to call `EndInvoke`.

Comment: Interesting. Why? I've never seen anyone say you have to do this.

Comment: So, looking this up a bit after this comment, the only reason I have seen put forward is that if you fire off a large number of asynchronous methods without calling EndInvoke, you could potentially starve the system until it garbage collects. But if you're only firing off a few delegates, why would it matter?

Comment: The GC will not collect the AsyncResults until you call EndInvoke.

Comment: @SLaks is correct, BeginInvoke allocates a wait handle, which would not be reclaimed until garbage collection if `EndInvoke()` is not called. @Jon Skeet has a nice sample for a Fire-and-Forget delegate wrapper here: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/threadpool.shtml